# Old questions showing recent activity

Tags: discussion, questions

Why do some questions come to the top of the active list when nothing seems to have been changed?

Example question:[Old question without noticeable activity](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/167663/66520)

Answer (score 8):

If you look at [the timeline](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/167663/timeline) for that question you will see an entry

> bumped by community user

Some questions are occasionally "bumped" by the community user. See [this meta answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285979/1703778)

> The Community user randomly bumps old, unanswered questions to bring them to the attention of users and [maybe] get them answered

Comment: Note for clarity, [unanswered](https://dba.stackexchange.com/unanswered) in Stack Exchange context means: the question has some answers, but there are no accepted nor upvoted answers. It doesn't mean [no answers](https://dba.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers). Now that the answers on the linked question have been upvoted, it won't be randomly bumped by the Community bot anymore.